# Display hidden css class on hover

Tags: css

I have few form fields, each input and label is wrapped inside a div in following way:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" />
    <p class="hint">Enter your name</p>
</div>
```

the hint class is initially hidden like `display:none.`

How can I display the hidden hint class on hover anywhere in  class field.
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In CSS you can do it the following way:

```
.hint { display: none; }
.field:hover .hint { display: block; }
```

**Edit:** As Karl said, this will not work in Internet Explorer 6. You can, however, resort to JavaScript (in this example using jQuery) to do that:

```
jQuery(".field").hover(
   function() {
      jQuery(this).find(".hint").css("display","block");
   },
   function() {
      jQuery(this).find(".hint").css("display","none");
   }
);
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this won't work on IE6 if that is a factor.

Answer (score 2):

This option will work in IE 4 and later.

```
<div class="field" onmouseover="document.getElementById('hint').style.display='none';"  onmouseout="document.getElementById('hint').style.display='block';">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" />
    <p id="hint">Enter your name</p>
</div>
```

And for your other forms just change the id hint2, hint3, etc.

```
<div class="field" onmouseover="document.getElementById('hint2').style.display='none';"  onmouseout="document.getElementById('hint2').style.display='block';">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" />
    <p id="hint2">Enter your name</p>
</div>
```